# Coupon control: Wordpress plug-in issue

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have some troubles with my WordPress plug-in. I'm a PHP beginner, so I merge some forums' tips and chunks of code. The plugin's purpose is to allow you to buy a selected product (through WooCommerce) on the website only if you have a coupon code.

```
function available_coupon_codes()
{
    global $wpdb;

    // Get an array of all existing coupon codes
    $coupon_codes = $wpdb->get_col(
        "SELECT post_name FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'shop_coupon' 
                              AND post_status = 'publish' ORDER BY post_name ASC");

    // Return array of available coupon codes
    return $coupon_codes; // always use return in a shortcode
}

function mandatory_coupon_code()
{
    $targeted_ids = array(236116); // The targeted product ids (in this array)
    $coupon_codes = available_coupon_codes();
    $coupons_found = array_intersect(array_filter(array_map('sanitize_title', 
        $coupon_codes)),
        WC()->cart->get_applied_coupons());

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item) {
        // Check cart item for defined product Ids and applied coupon
        if (in_array($item['product_id'], $targeted_ids) && empty($coupons_found)) {
            wc_clear_notices(); // Clear all other notices

            // Avoid checkout displaying an error notice
            wc_add_notice(sprintf(
                'Pro zakoupení "%s" je potřeba zadat kód květinového předplatného.
            ', $item['data']->get_name()), 'error');
            break; // stop the loop
        }
    }
}

add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'mandatory_coupon_code', 10, 0);
```

After the plugin activates, my WordPress freeze until plugin deactivation (rename of plugin folder through FTP). If possible, please tell me where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

It  occurs due to code freeze, and your wordpress become in a read only state
so,
please find the code freeze in your plugin and then upload it...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I'm not sure if is that problem what you mentioned. After activation of the plugin a get warning of "unexpected output" of 3 character length.